# jQuery: Bind onClick to all anchors pointing to other pages with target=_self

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to call my custom function (or simply execute certain logic) whenever user clicks on any `a` that **does not open in a new window** and has `href` attribute which is **not empty** and **does not start with `#`** and **does not have `javascript:`**.

Basically I need all those links that, if clicked will lead to the current page be unloaded. But all other links like `#point1` or `javascript:alert('');`, etc. should be excluded (because if clicked the user will still remain on the page). What is the proper jQuery for that?

Ideally should be compatible with older jQuery - version 1.7.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href][href!=""]:not([href^="#"],[href^="javascript:"],[target="_blank"])', function() {
    // do something
})
```

But, you have to consider that it's not a very readable code to maintain. Passing a filter function (like in @Rory McCrossan answer) can be more readable.

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kb2czb3x/4/)

P.S Have you considered using the [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) event instead?

Comment: +1 for using a delegated handler, with selector. FYI You should as a matter of habit use `$(document)` and not `body` for delegated handlers. `body` has a bug to do with styling.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, Thanks. Updated.

Comment: So I should then use [href^="#"] for does not start with condition, and also should append [href^="javascript:"]?

Comment: @FitDev, I updated the answer with the correct handling of `#`

Comment: Oh I see you just answered it with an edit. Thank you!

Comment: Just to clarify, in your latest edit not acts as OR inside, that is it will work if ANY of the NOTed conditions is present (not all of them must be present)?

Comment: @FitDev, It seems to act in an AND way. See the updated Fiddle

Answer (score 2):

As that's quite a complex set of rules you could use a `filter()`:

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    return href != '' && href != '#someanchor' && this.target != '_blank';
}).click(function() {
    // do your thing here...
});
```

Comment: A single delegated handler, no matter how complex the jQuery selector, will always perform better than loads of individual click handlers.

Comment: I agree, although @haim770 laid claim to that answer :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, +1 But, any reason you insist on `attr('href')` instead of `this.href`?

Comment: @Haim770 thanks for the edit, however I specifically used the `href` via `attr()` as it gives you the attribute value from the DOM. Using `this.href` means that the URL is made absolute which can lead to differences. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zcgrpdum/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I see

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's `.not()` method. See: http://api.jquery.com/not/

```
$('a')
   .not('[target=_blank]')
   .not('[href=""]')
   .not('[href=#someanchor]')
   .on('click', function() {
      //code here
   });
```